# Browser not playing audio returned with Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, audio, mp3

I have a simple Python Flask application I'm using to return images and audio I generate server side (separately). My image code looks like this:

```
# various cv2 calls to generate an image
image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.png', image)
return Response(image_bytes[1].tobytes(), mimetype='image/png', status=200)
```

That works fine. However, I can't seem to get audio returned. Here's that code:

```
AUDIO_FORMAT = 'audio/mp3'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "accept": AUDIO_FORMAT}
payload = {"text": text}
# call to generate audio from text
response = requests.post()
if response.status_code == 200:
    sound_data = response.content
    f = open('audio.mp3', 'wb')
    f.write(sound_data)
    f.close()
    return Response(sound_data,
                    mimetype=AUDIO_FORMAT,
                    status=200)
```

When I play the `audio.mp3` file, I hear the audio I expect. And when the response renders in the browser, I get the audio player. But I hear nothing and I get a length of 00:00. I'm thinking there's an encoding/translation step I'm missing.

Comment: have you provided the audio absolute path or relative path, check that first also

Comment: A bit more information. The file I write, I can open in a browser and it plays fine. When I write that audio file to the Flask `/static` directory and then return it with `return send_from_directory('static/audio', audio_filename)` I get the same browser error. In the console I see, `Error: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

Comment: Yeah, the path doesn't appear to be the issue. I can put a `.json` or a `.html` file in the same directory as the audio files, return it with the same code, and the browser understands it.

Comment: Good to know, maybe if you didn't get any solution here, I suggest you to ask in discord flask server there you can get help for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was on the right path writing the audio to a file and returning that file. In my first comment, I stated that writing the audio to a file and using `send_from_directory` was failing. Well, it was, but because of a separate error. Once I fixed that, it worked.

```
return send_from_directory('static/audio', file_name)
```

I think I understand why my original approach was not working. When the browser saw the audio mimetype, it attempted to play it with the audio control. That audio control has a `src` attribute pointing back to the audio I sent. The subsequent call back to my server from the audio control correctly fails, because I didn't persist that audio and provide a path to it.